# Will this quartz connector I configured pick only one file at a time

Tags: java, spring, file, mule

This is the mule config file for a service of a class , that basically reads order file and processes it. Sometime the code is confused and it processes two or more file and getting freezed. I want the code to read only one file at a time.

```
  <quartz-connector name = "oneThreadQuartzConnector">
   <quartz:factory-property key ="org.quartz.threadpool.threadcount" value="1"/>
   </quartz-connector>
    <service name="Retail Transfer Request Service">
        <inbound>
            <file:inbound-endpoint path="#{es.dir.008}" moveToDirectory="#{es.dir.008}/archive/ORD">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="OR*" />
            </file:inbound-endpoint>
        </inbound>

        <component>
            <spring-object bean="retailTransferRequestAction" />
        </component>

        <default-service-exception-strategy>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="found.error.queue" />
        </default-service-exception-strategy>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

The quartz will pick data one by one if you want to make a synchronous call the best option is to choose processing strategy in the flow and make it synchronous

```
<flow name="sampleFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
```